# iOS remove or transfer reserved app provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have developed an app using a temporary personal team provisioning profile which does not have an Apple developer account subscription. Now that I finally want to publish my app I want to use another developer account which has the developer account.

How can I remove the provisioning profile from one developer account to be able to add it in another account?

I have also tried removing the provisioning from the Mac that I'm building on but that doesn't mean I can register it with the other account. Also I can't access app sections of the developer panel in Apple Developers site since the first account doesn't have a developer licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with the provisioning profile from the free account.  Those profiles are created on demand and only work for 7 days.  You will simply need to add the application ID for the app to your real developer account, generate a distribution certificate and profile for the new app, and use that cert / key / profile to code sign the app for submitting to the App Store.

Comment: Yes I did exactly that. But for the time being I can't build with debug which is not nice. Apple should provide a facility to remove that.

Comment: You will also need to generate a new development cert and provisioning profile if you want to do debug builds.